# What happens when I ping 127.0.0.1

Tags: ping, network-protocols

It might seem a little stupid but I'm curious to know what really happens when I ping the loop-back IP address, `ping 127.0.0.1`.

Does OS treat it in a special way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `127.0.0.0/8` is a [CDIR netblock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) reserved by [IANA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_assigned_/8_IPv4_address_blocks) and it's called Loopback. This traffic is routed by kernel to a a special network adapter called `loopback adapter`. It never hits the [OSI Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) Layer 1, as any local traffic.

For most all OS data travels across the network kernel services until the IP stack. At this point the data will be send back without hitting the physical layer and the real NIC hardware.

This work is done almost entirely from the host system's CPU, which means a great simplification compared to the physical network transmission. Modern OS kernels are able to detect the loopback traffic and grant speeds over than fastest nowadays physical adapters (> 50GBps).

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that OS treats this IP any different from the rest except that it points back to local machine.

http://www.rolo.org/127-0-0-1.html

Comment: I knew that much, but I want more details. for example, How can I change this address to my custom-arbitrary address in my Windows/Ubuntu ? Does it need a hack or not ?

Comment: It is part of convention that's been in place for years now. Unless you build your OS code to treat some other IP address as loop back or setup a firewall that redirects all the requests to a specific set of IP addresses to your loop back address (which is 127.0.0.1), I do not see any other way out.